# An Error Occurred While Downloading A Required File

Tags: wpf, web, setup-project

I'm not sure if this is the right forum or not, since I have no idea what's causing this problem.  I have a WPF application that was compiled into a setup project.  After building the setup project, there are two files: setup.exe and [Program Name].msi.  I put both files in the same directory in an ASP.NET website, served via IIS 7.5.  Everything was working fine for about a week, until I started getting the error:

> "An error occured while downloading a
>   required file.  You may retry
>   downloading the file or cancel setup."

This happens when I click on a link on my website for the setup.exe file.  After seeing this error, there's a tab labeled "Details" which I can click to display the message:

> "An error occurred trying to download
>   '[website url for the .msi file]'. See
>   the setup log file located at
>   'C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp[some
>   alphanumeric
>   sequence].tmp\install.log' for more
>   information."

I looked at this file, but it just restates that there was a problem downloading the .msi file.  Can anyone offer me some suggestions?  I'm really stumped on this, and have no idea where to go...

Many thanks for the help!

Andrew

EDIT:  This appears to be a problem with the computer that I'm downloading the program to.  I tried downloading and installing the program on a different computer, and everything worked fine.  Apparently, I must have changed some setting on my computer to cause this, although I'm not sure what that is...

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to download these files directly? Could the server be preventing the download of the .msi file type? How is the download taking place? Is it user initiated?

Comment: Hi Matthew, it is user initiated.  I have an asp:Button on the website, and the click event initiates a Response.Redirect("[url for setup.exe]"); command.  This would cause a window to popup, asking if the user would like to save or run the file.  Clicking run would, in the past, cause the setup program to run.  But now, I'm just getting the error mentioned above...

Comment: After reading your edit to your original question, I'm guessing it could be a security issue (IE, FF, security settings on the computer...). Is it necessary to have the .exe downloaded as such? Could you not bundle the .exe with the .msi in a zip file? I have a feeling this would help.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue this morning and I finally figured out that it caused by  either one (or both) of the following settings in IIS:

1. Compression: I had compression enabled for both static and dynamic files
2. Output Caching: I had bit Enable cache and Enable Kernel Cache enabled

I cleared all of the above check boxes and after that the setup.exe downloaded the MSI without a problem!

Answer (score 0):

You connection was interrupted just try the preview command you type and also check your connection